# Java: Inmutable static variable, possible?

Tags: java

I have a class with this, it's an example code, not the real code

```
private static String className;

public static Wish getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    if(wish == null)
        wish = new Wish();

    className = clazz.getName();
    return wish;
}
```

Many classes use this `Wish` class, then each class should "say" a wish with the `className` passed in the `getInstance` method.

Then I have something like this

```
public class Boy {
    private Wish w = Wish.getInstance(Boy.class);
    //at this moment the static variable take "com.package.Boy" value
....
}
```

Another classs

```
public class Girl {
    private Wish w = Wish.getInstance(Girl.class);
    //at this moment the static variable take "com.package.Girl" value
....
}
```

When everybody start to say their wishes, example

```
public class WishesDay {
    private Girl g;
    private Boy b;

    public void makeYourWish() {
        g = new Girl(); //get the com.package.Girl value
        b = new Boy(); //get the com.package.Boy value

        //sample output "com.package.Boy wants A pink house!"
        g.iWish("A pink house!"); // the boys don't want this things :(
        b.iWish("A spatial boat!"); 
    }
}
```

I know that each object have the same copy o the `Wish` class and the static variable `className` change when each object (`Girl, Boy`) call the `Wish.getInstance(Class<?> clazz)` method.

How can I use a static variable (I want avoid to instantiate the Wish class) and keep the correct value for the variable `className`.

Can I make this with a static variable? or the solution is to instantiate (no static variable)

For example, `log4j` has the `Logger` class, I want to make the same thing with the class name.

Comment: There aren't static classes in Java. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking to do, but I think you're wanting to use the singleton pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: How does iWish method looks like?

Comment: Just makes an output `System.out.println(w.className + " wants " + strWish);`

Comment: Then I don't understand the intention to store class name in Wish class, since you call instance method on Boy/Girl class. You can replace w.className with this.getClass().getName()

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make sense.  You could also instantiate a new Wish for each class like `Wish w = new Wish(Girl.class)` and then each Wish has it's own (non-static) properties.

Comment: Please provide compilable source for Wish class. Also clarify what is it that you are trying to achieve, i.e. is it a mapping from classes to instances of Wish?

Comment: Huumm ... isn't the real code, it's a way to say that I want to make, my requirement is that the class name is in a static variable in other class like Wish class

Comment: I'm going to change the Girl and Boy example :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make your constructor private if you want to avoid instantiate the Wish class and make the className not static.

```
public class Wish {

    String className;


    private Wish(String className){
        this.className = className;
    }

    public static Wish getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        String className = clazz.getName();
        return new Wish(className);
    }    
    public String getClassName() {

        return className;
    }

}



package com.test;
public class WishesDay {
    private Girl g;
    private Boy b;

    public void makeYourWish() {
        g = new Girl(); //get the com.package.Girl value
        b = new Boy(); //get the com.package.Boy value

        //sample output "com.package.Boy wants A pink house!"
        g.iWish("A pink house!"); // the boys don't want this things :(
        b.iWish("A spatial boat!"); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WishesDay wd = new WishesDay();


        wd.makeYourWish();
        //outputs com.test.Girl wants A pink house!
        //com.test.Boy wants A spatial boat!


    }

}
```

Comment: Please see this https://github.com/ropherpanama/implementations/blob/master/issues/question_1 i think that the example it's better, I will try your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @RosendoRopher I saw that link and they have the same issue as you posted and I've check the implementation of a few loggers org.slf4j, for example and they keep the class name non-static as I do

Comment: Yeah, but indirectly (by the getInstance) this makes a new instance of the object. It's the correct way, can this impact negatively in any way? Many many classes will call this "write" process. The positive is that now keep the correct value :)

Comment: This way is just hell better, because by doing this you could avoid a lot issues that may arise later on like the one you posted or even worst like concurrency issues .  I would just like to suggest to separate the responsability of creating the instances into another class something like "WishFactory". Look at this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottdensmore/2004/05/25/why-singletons-are-evil/) if you want to read further

Comment: [Why Singletons are Evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottdensmore/2004/05/25/why-singletons-are-evil/)